# Problemas con la etiqueta "Autorize" en asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core

He estado usando ASP.NET Core 2.1 y a la hora de acceder como un usuario no autenticado he decidido usar la etiqueta `[Authorize]` en el controlador, la etiqueta funciona perfectamente, sin embargo, a la hora de realizar la redirección accede a la siguiente url:

```
https://localhost:44346/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FPosts%2FDelete%2F2
```

mientras que la dirección correcta ha de ser

```
https://localhost:44346/Identity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FPosts%2FDelete%2F2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en `Startup.cs` copia las siguentes lineas dentro del metodo `ConfigureServices()`

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
```